# How can I keep my Raspbian "Wheezy" up to date?

Tags: raspbian, update

Is there a sort of update tool for my Raspbian [Debian 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Wheezy) package?

I installed `php` and `lighttpd`, and I want to keep those automatically updated for when bugs are found.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to enter some commands into the command line.
First of all:

```
apt-get update
```

(this will update the sources of software)

```
apt-get upgrade
```

(this will upgrade everything to the latest version)

Comment: Is that all ther's to it? Will it upgrade everyting i installed via apt-get, including the Os itself?

Comment: The "OS itself" being the linux kernel, yes.  The first time you do this there will probably be a bunch of updates since the repository will usually contain newer packages than the install image.

Comment: Everything that came from the apt repo, that is. Which is normally everything except your data, but might not include e.g. the kernel or bootloader in this case. If you've downloaded stuff from elsewhere or made some of your own, that obviously can't be automagically upgraded :)

Comment: Yep, that's all there is to it. You might have to answer the occasional yes/no question for larger pieces of software, but basically, it's that easy.

Comment: @Goldilocks with the OS i think i mean the linix kernal yes, but i'm not sure. I come from a windows world and there i have a separated 'windows update' which updates the OS (windows and windows parts like IIS), so i call all that 'the OS'

Comment: @Michel : Sometimes "the linux OS" is more broadly referred to as "GNU/Linux" which would include the kernel ("linux" in the strict sense) and userspace fundamentals such as the C library, shell, etc, which are under the GNU umbrella.  With windows, all these parts are immutably integrated, whereas the linux world is more heterogeneous and modular, so there can be some confusion.  I would have taken "the OS" here to refer to the debian wheezy distro (including the kernel), but you seemed to be referring to something more specific.

Comment: @Michel: If you want some further reading about the package management system on debian (raspbian is based on debian), start here: http://wiki.debian.org/Apt

Comment: @Goldilocks no on, you are right, the debian wheezy distro is what i think is the OS. That is a good description.

Answer (score 41):

The `unattended-upgrades` package is the way to automate updating the OS in these debian-family distributions. Follow instructions found in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html).

Basically you have to install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

and add to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` the following:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Additionally (since it seems like the porting of the package has not been flawless), change the following line at the first section of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
        "origin=Debian,archive=stable,label=Debian-Security";
```

to

```
//        "origin=Debian,archive=stable,label=Debian-Security";
        "origin=Raspbian";
```

Now your system keeps itself up-to-date automatically.

Comment: The last step (swapping out `origin=Debian`) is no longer necessary in the latest distribution of Raspbian.

Comment: On Raspbian Wheezy, today, it seems to be still necessary as, for example: `Checking: openssl (["<Origin component:'main' archive:'oldstable' origin:'Raspbian' label:'Raspbian' site:'mirrordirector.raspbian.org' isTrusted:True>"])`

Comment: Oops, I misread. Yes, `origin=Raspbian` is still necessary in the configuration file but, no, you don't need to do it yourself anymore indeed, sorry...

Answer (score 25):

**Dist:**

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Rpi-update first time:**
install git and certifications for reach github.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
$ sudo wget http://goo.gl/1BOfJ -O /usr/bin/rpi-update
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-update
```

update firmware

```
$ sudo rpi-update
$ sudo ldconfig
$ sudo reboot
```

**Rpi-update after:**

```
$ sudo rpi-update
$ sudo ldconfig
$ sudo reboot
```

[rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update)

Answer (score 5):

rpi-update can now be fetched directly via apt-get, so there would be no need to deal with [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget). So here is now the updated way:

**Dist:**

```
 $ sudo apt-get update
 $ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

You need to reboot the Raspberry Pi now, otherwise the new kernel would not be used!

**Rpi-update first time:**
Install [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) and certifications to reach [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub).

```
$ sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
$ sudo apt-get install rpi-update
```

Update firmware

```
$ sudo rpi-update
$ sudo reboot
```

[rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update)

Answer (score 3):

You could also write a little script with your apt-get steps in there and run it on a schedule once a day / however often you like, that's what I've done.

How to set up a cron job on the Pi:

http://www.wexoo.net/20130406/running-cron-jobs-on-raspberry-pi-in-raspbmc

How to write a bash script:

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/284789-writing-a-simple-bash-script-

My script was just a simple

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -yes
apt-get dist-upgrade -yes
apt-get clean
```

and I had it logging the output to a file with `>>` at the end of each line, e.g. `apt-get update >> autoupdate.txt`.

It's debatable as to how good an idea it is to do this though!

Comment: Any chance you could share the script &/or info on how to do these timed events. I imagine if the OP knew how to do this, he wouldn't have posted.

Answer (score 1):

[The Art of Web](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/cron-apt-wheezy/) site has a wonderfull guide for Debian Wheezy that I only had to modify **one** line for it to work on my testing RPi. The link will take you to thier guide on `cron-apt`; which has been peraphrased bellow with modification for RPi repos' system explained.

Install cron-apt

`sudo apt-get install cron-apt`

Default configuration, actions, and custom configs can be found with

`ls -hal /etc/cron-apt/config`

`ls -hal /etc/cron-apt/action.d/`

`ls -hal /etc/cron-apt/config.d/`

Append the following to `/etc/cron-apt/config` file with `sudo tee -a` to enable emails to be sent with verbos information on the actions taken during automated update

`echo 'MAILON="output"' | sudo tee -a /etc/cron-apt/config`

`echo 'DEBUG="verbose"' | sudo tee -a /etc/cron-apt/config`

Logging is dumped to : `/var/log/cron-apt/log`

Make new action file for updating only security related packeges with touch command and add one line with sudo tee command; others will be downloaded but wait for sys-admin to install non-security updates. Allerts of updates and output will be emailed to root user or sys-admin for further review and/or actions to be taken.

`sudo touch /etc/cron-apt/action.d/5-security`

`echo 'upgrade -y -o APT::Get::Show-Upgraded=true' | sudo tee -a /etc/cron-apt/action.d/5-security`

Make new configuration file to use above action; spicifficly using `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/security.list` as the path for security updates. The file path maybe differant on your system if not fully based on Debian Linux; RPi now uses mirror director so `/etc/apt/sources.list` should be used instead, however, this can not be advised for production level servers because it'll update non-security updates too.

`sudo touch /etc/cron-apt/config.d/5-security`

`echo 'OPTIONS="-o quiet=1 -o APT::Get::List-Cleanup=false -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/security.list -o Dir::Etc::SourceParts=\"/dev/null\""' | sudo tee -a /etc/cron-apt/config.d/5-security`

Wait a day for `cron-apt` to update your system and check local logs with the following to see what was updated while you slept

`sudo cat /var/log/cron-apt/log`

This has been tested on one RPi to work for updating every package as well as an Unbuntu PC that only updates security related packages. So I feel that it is one of the more portable options availabe. The other package for automated updates, suggested by grassroot (thank you, I'm going to test it next), `unattended-upgrades` seemes like another great option to automate the update process.